# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable python 3.7.0

Tags: python

I've been trying to create a Minmax Agent for search algorithm, and is struggling to find why this is giving me an error:

```
def getAction(self, gameState):
    def isTerminalState(gameState):
        if (gameState.isWin() or gameState.isLose() or self.depth == 0):
            return True;
        return False;

    def max_value(state, depth):
        if isTerminalState(state):
            return self.evaluationFunction(state)

        depth -= 1
        maximum_value = float("-inf")
        maximum_action = None
        for action in state.getLegalActions(0):
            next_state = state.generateSuccessor(0, action)
            num_ghosts = state.getNumAgents() - 1
            temp_value = min_value(next_state, depth, num_ghosts)
            if temp_value > maximum_value:
                maximum_value = temp_value
                maximum_action = action
        return (maximum_value, maximum_action)

    def min_value(state, depth, num_ghosts):
        if isTerminalState(state):
            return self.evaluationFunction(state)

        minimum_value = float("inf")
        if num_ghosts is 1:
            for action in state.getLegalActions(1):
                next_state = state.generateSuccessor(1, action)
                temp_value = max_value(next_state, depth)[0]
                if temp_value < minimum_value:
                    minimum_value = temp_value
                return minimum_value
        else:
            list = []
            if num_ghosts > 1:
                for action in state.getLegalActions(i):
                    next_state = state.generateSuccessor(i, action)
                    list.append(min_value(next_state, depth, num_ghosts - 1))
            return min(list)

    return max_value(gameState, self.depth)[1]
```

The error is inside min_value(state, depth, num_ghosts), which is:

```
temp_value = max_value(next_state, depth)[0]
```

I'm trying to access maxium_value from the max_value function and the error I'm receiving is

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Someone please help :(

Comment: also share the code of `evaluationFunction` function

Comment: If you hit first `return` (the one inside the `if`), what do you receive? `return self.evaluationFunction(state)` - we can't see that function. I assume it's a single element, that's why you can't do `[0]` on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you what the issue is. Your returning a float from max_value instead of a tuple (or any other subscriptable data type).

```
            return self.evaluationFunction(state)
```

This is the line where you return a float. Post the code to this function if you want further help.